# c++: what exactly does &rand do?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, function-pointers, random

This is an excerpt of some c++ code, that i'll have to explain in detail in some days:

```
std::vector<int> vct(8, 5);

std::generate(vct.begin(), vct.end(), &rand);

std::copy(vct.rbegin(), vct.rend(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

i think i understand everything about it, except that tiny mystical &rand. what exactly does it do? i mean obviously it produces some kind of pseudo-random-numbers, but they always remain the same. where does the &rand come from? what kind of expression is it? where do the values it produces come from? i'm a bit confused…

also, i could neither find any other occurrences of the word "rand" in the code, nor did i see any code that could have something to do with random numbers. that made me wonder, because my (very limited) experience in c++ showed, that only very few things simply work without having to be declared or included previously.

thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `&` in `&rand` returns the address of the `rand()` function. You're passing a function pointer to `generate()` so `generate()` can call `rand()` to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 5):

**rand()** is a function from the C standard library which generates psuedo-random numbers between 0 and the define *`RAND_MAX`*. If you use C++, include the header `<cstdlib>` to use it (instead of `<stdlib.h>`) **srand()** lets you set a seed. If you want a new seed every time you run your application, you can seed with a value from time().

The *POSIX standard* from 2001 has an example-implementation of **rand()** and **srand()**. I copy-pasted it from my man pages. The implementation used by your C standard library might differ from this one:

```
static unsigned long next = 1;

/* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}

void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

Also, the **&** takes the address from the function. Compilers are kind of ambiguous on this part. Some require the use of this operator when you want addresses from function pointers; others don't. **generate** is a function from the `<algorithm>` header from the C++ standard library. It takes functions and/or functor objects and uses it to generate values for the container whos iterators you specify.

Answer (score 2):

`rand` is defined in cstdlib. You're getting the same value because you're using the same "seed". That's by design.

If you want a different seed, call `srand` first, e.g., `srand(time(NULL));`.

Comment: Hm can't decide whether yours or Ken's answer is better, but the combination is just what i needed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

rand() is a function that is part of the standard C library.  It's signature is:

```
int rand(void);
```

It's defined in stdlib.h.  Most likely, the implementation of your std C++ library is including that header file when you are including  or .

Answer (score 0):

`&rand` just means "the address of `rand`." `rand` is a function from the standard library which returns pseudo-random numbers. What you're doing is passing the address of this function to the algorithms. They then call this function during the course of their work.

As far as `rand` itself goes, any decent C++ documentation will tell you why it behaves the way you're observing... (and other answers here do as well)